# Unexpected Regex.Match outcome in C#

Tags: c#, regex

`Match match = Regex.Match(returnValue, @regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

The variables in the above line of code contain the following values:

`returnValue : "Tags"`

`@regex : "[A-Z][a-z][a-z]"`

I'm assuming the regex function match should fail as the word "Tags" has 3 lower case letters and not 2 as the regex variable shows. But, **match.Success always returns true** for the above code.

This has really got me confused, and any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**:

Here is a  more detailed explanation on what I need. I'm trying to create something like a regex generator.

The user enters `A` for upper, `a` for lower and `d` for digits. Now if the user passes a word like `Tags`, I check the passed string to see if it fits into the user specified rule.

Here's my current logic:

```
  if (patternChars[strIndex] == 'A') 
{
     regexBuilder.Append("[A-Z]");
} else if (patternChars[strIndex] == 'a') 
{
     regexBuilder.Append("[a-z]");
} else if (patternChars[strIndex] == 'd') 
{
     regexBuilder.Append("\\d");
} else {
     regexBuilder.Append(patternChars[strIndex]);
}
```

I'm guessing this needs to be changed?

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: It does match part of the input string. If you want to match only the full input string then you have to use start and end metacharacters. For more information just take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: @R.T."Tags" with [upper],[lower],[lower] and I expect it to fail but it does not.

Comment: I updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @isnot2bad The user passes 2 strings `("Aaa","Tag")` and then I compare the 2 accordingly and display if the expression is a pass or fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@regex : "^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]$"
```

Explanation:

- `$` matches the line end,so your third group will match the lower case `g`, but then there are additional characters, causing `$` not to match.
- `^` matches the line start, preventing matches in the middle of the string, e,g `guten Tag` or `aaaAaa`

This should match only `Tag`, but not `Tags`. But it would also match `Zag`, `Aaa`, etc. pp. - do you really want that?

Third edit:
you are using this line:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(returnValue, @regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Why are you ignoring the case when you are doing case sensitive matches?

for your edit:
It depends - WHEN your user wants to find that in a string, it is ok. If you want to find out if a given string as whole matches, you need to prepend "^" and append "$" at the end.

Comment: But it also matches "guten Tag". Improve to "^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]$"

Comment: @ChristianSauer:- Dont be! Keep my +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]$
```

[Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/jC3qU6/2)

Answer (score 1):

The Match(String, String, RegexOptions) method returns the first substring that matches a regular expression pattern in an input string;

```
 regexBuilder.Append("^");
  if (patternChars[strIndex] == 'A') 
{
 regexBuilder.Append("[A-Z]");
} else if (patternChars[strIndex] == 'a') 
{
 regexBuilder.Append("[a-z]");
} else if (patternChars[strIndex] == 'd') 
{
  regexBuilder.Append("\\d");
} else {
 regexBuilder.Append(patternChars[strIndex]);
}
regexBuilder.Append("$");
```